# wagtail uploads and Django deploy not from project_root?

Tags: python, django, wagtail

Am a little confused here, using [Wagtail](http://wagtail.io) (Django variant CMS), on virtualenv, FastCGI, on served on shared hosting.

my settings.py

```
import os

PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '..', '..')

DEBUG = False
TEMPLATE_DEBUG = DEBUG    
PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '..', '..')

    MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'media')
    MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
    STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'static')
    STATIC_URL = '/static/'
    STATICFILES_DIRS = ()
```

When I run `./manage.py collectstatic` my static files are correctly compiled into `~/myproj/static` however the Django template debug insists on looking at `~/env/lib/python2.7/static` for the css files. If I upload my personal css files there though, it messes up the css of Wagtail.

Also, when I upload images through the Wagtail dashboard, they go straight to `~/env/lib/python2.7/static`

What am I getting wrong here? Why isn't it serving from `~/myproj/static`?

Answer (score 2):

Django intentionally doesn't serve static files when it's in production mode (DEBUG = False), because it's more efficient for your webserver to serve those files directly, and take Django out of the process. It's up to you to configure the webserver to do this, but [the Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/howto/static-files/deployment/) offers some pointers.

(I don't know where your Django installation is getting ~/env/lib/python2.7/static from, though.)

Comment: Right, i did indeed follow the documentation. and have no issues with my static files in production or development mode. Was just wondering if I should be concern about my Django looking to `~/env/lib/python2.7/static ` which makes me worry I've got something wrong somewhere.